# Access calendar events without user login with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I need help with Microsoft Graph access without user login. I am trying to access `events/` endpoint without any success so far.

From the following graph API app
[image: Graph API App]
with the following permissions
[image]
and following account type
[image]

I can get a [userless access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)[image]
and I can access `users` [image]
and also with id
[image]
but not the calendar
[image]

Though the HTTP response code is `401 Unauthorized` the error `OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound` looks like a permission issue.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: Maybe that tenant does not have Exchange Online, or the user doesn't have an Exchange Online mailbox? I notice the user doesn't have the `mail` property populated, which it should be.

Comment: This account (in the screenshots above) is my personal account (@bluewin.ch). I don't know why the mail isn't showing. Do you think I should try with an @outlook.com account?

Comment: Yes - Graph can only access calendars in Exchange Online mailboxes or Outlook.com mailboxes.

Comment: Be aware though that client credential flow doesn't work with Outlook.com - you have to use delegated auth there (a user token).

Answer (score 1):

In order for a call to `/users/{user-id}/events` to work the user indicated by `user-id` MUST have a mailbox on Exchange Online if you use client credentials.

You indicated in the comments that the user was your personal account, maybe it has been added as a "guest" user in your organization? In that case the user account wouldn't have a mailbox (which makes sense with the `mail` property being null), so the call wouldn't work.